# Single-row subquery returns more than one row in select while executing a Select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the ORA-01427 error while running the below SQL query. I'm not sure which aggregate function I need to use in the below sub query to solve this.

```
select distinct 
    x.por_s, x.com_s, x.reg_s, x.off_s, x.lse_s, 
    y.les_s, y.client_s_name_s,
    z.DLR_S, k.nam_long_s, z.ID_S, z.res_d, y.short_add_s, 
    y.short_cty_s, y.st_s, y.bus_phn_s, x.d_mat_s, 
    x.d_lsd_s, x.trm_l, x.tot_org_d, 
    x.tot_org_d - x.acl_depr_d as rem_net_inv,
    (select rgr.nam_long_s 
     from rgr 
     inner join vrcx_grt on rgr.grn_s = vrcx_grt.grn_s) as Client_Name,
    n.bus_phn_s,n.hom_phn_s,o.field19_s, o.field20_s
from 
    rls x, vrcx_les y, req z, rlr k, ral n, rug o, rgr m, vrcx_grt p 
where 
    x.les_s = y.les_s
    and x.LSE_S = z.LSE_S
    and z.dlr_s = k.dlr_s
    and x.les_s = n.les_s
    and x.lse_s = o.lse_s
    and m.GRN_S = p.GRN_S
    and x.por_s = ' 1'
    and x.act_s in ('AACQ', 'AASM', 'AEXM', 'ANOR', 'ARBK', 'ARED', 'AREN', 'AXFR')
    and x.d_mat_s > to_date ('07/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
order by 
    x.D_MAT_S, y.les_s
```

Comment: Run `select rgr.nam_long_s from rgr inner join vrcx_grt on rgr.grn_s = 
vrcx_grt.grn_s` on its own and see how many rows are returned..If the answer is not always 1 then you'll  get that error. Is it supposed to be correlated to the rest of the query, and if it was would that always return one row then?

Comment: "(select rgr.nam_long_s from rgr inner join vrcx_grt on rgr.grn_s = 
vrcx_grt.grn_s) as Client_Name" is odd. Does it always return a single row?

Comment: @AlexPoole it's returning more than 1 row. What needs to be done to avoid this?

Comment: We don't know your data. I imagine there is supposed to be some correlation involved - some link between those two tables and between the 8 in the main query. Is it right that the subquery hits the same tables as are in the main query? I'm not sure why you aren't just getting the name from the `rgr m` in the main query - do you really need the subquery at all? i.e. if you replace the entire subquery expression with `m.name_long_s as Client_Name` do you get the result you wanted?

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried it by replacing the entire subquery with m.name_long_s but it is  bringing all the unwanted data irrespective of the condition which i used in the Where clause "and m.GRN_S = p.GRN_S". When i dont include that column in the query im getting correct results. But i need to get that column data also in the extract.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written your query with the old style join syntax which makes it fairly unreadable. How about rewriting as:

```
select distinct x.por_s, x.com_s, x.reg_s, x.off_s, x.lse_s,y.les_s,
                y.client_s_name_s,z.DLR_S,k.nam_long_s,z.ID_S,z.res_d, y.short_add_s,
                y.short_cty_s, y.st_s, y.bus_phn_s, x.d_mat_s,
                x.d_lsd_s, x.trm_l, x.tot_org_d, x.tot_org_d - x.acl_depr_d as rem_net_inv,
                m.nam_long_s as Client_Name,
                n.bus_phn_s,n.hom_phn_s,o.field19_s, o.field20_s
from rls x
    inner join vrcx_les y on x.les_s = y.les_s
    inner join req z on x.LSE_S = z.LSE_S
    inner join rlr k on z.dlr_s = k.dlr_s
    inner join ral n on x.les_s = n.les_s
    inner join rug o on x.lse_s = o.lse_s 
    inner join rgr m on m.les_s = x.les_s
    inner join vrcx_grt p on m.grn_s = p.grn_s
where 
  and x.por_s = ' 1'
  and x.act_s in ('AACQ', 'AASM', 'AEXM', 'ANOR', 'ARBK', 'ARED', 'AREN',
                  'AXFR')
  and x.d_mat_s > to_date ('07/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
order by x.D_MAT_S, y.les_s
```

Here p (vrcx_grt) doesn't seem to have any role other than acting as an "EXISTS" check. You could have written that as:

```
select distinct x.por_s, x.com_s, x.reg_s, x.off_s, x.lse_s,y.les_s,
                y.client_s_name_s,z.DLR_S,k.nam_long_s,z.ID_S,z.res_d, y.short_add_s,
                y.short_cty_s, y.st_s, y.bus_phn_s, x.d_mat_s,
                x.d_lsd_s, x.trm_l, x.tot_org_d, x.tot_org_d - x.acl_depr_d as rem_net_inv,
                m.nam_long_s as Client_Name,
                n.bus_phn_s,n.hom_phn_s,o.field19_s, o.field20_s
from rls x
    inner join vrcx_les y on x.les_s = y.les_s
    inner join req z on x.LSE_S = z.LSE_S
    inner join rlr k on z.dlr_s = k.dlr_s
    inner join ral n on x.les_s = n.les_s
    inner join rug o on x.lse_s = o.lse_s 
    inner join rgr m on m.les_s = x.les_s
where 
  and x.por_s = ' 1'
  and x.act_s in ('AACQ', 'AASM', 'AEXM', 'ANOR', 'ARBK', 'ARED', 'AREN',
                  'AXFR')
  and x.d_mat_s > to_date ('07/01/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  and EXISTS (select * from vrcx_grt p where m.grn_s = p.grn_s)
order by x.D_MAT_S, y.les_s
```

Note: Ooops. After rewriting your query, I noticed that there isn't any relation between m\p and the rest of tables. If you correct that all should be fine.

EDIT: Edited the queries based on your info.

Comment: When i tried to executing the above query it says p.GRN_s is invalid identifier. But thats a valid statement.

Comment: @RaviRock, No, I didn't remove that from the queries but as I noted at bottom both m and p don't have any relations to the rest of the tables. How does m relate to others?

Comment: m and p are related to rls,ral,vrcx_les where one column is matching to them.

Comment: If i am removing those 2 join conditions for m and p im unable to get the colum data for m.nam_long_s in the extract

Comment: @RaviRock, just tell me this, how does rgr (m) relate to any of the tables? (except p)

Comment: rgr is related to rls,ral,vrcx_les. These are related with columns rgr.grn_s, rls.les_s,ral.les_s and vrcx_les.les_s

Comment: @RaviRock, OK when there is multiple relations it is you who would decide to relate with which one. I am simply selecting rls.les_s as the relation and editing the queries.

Comment: One more suggestion i need.With the previous query (Before Editing) when i tried to execute it throws the error p.GRN_S is invalid identifier. How to avoid this error.

Comment: @RaviRock, provide the correct identifier (vrcx_grt)  - then you would also need to add it to join, unnecessary IMHO  (I left it there as is, knowing it was invalid)

Comment: Those are the correct Identifiers which we used in the Query for vrcx_grt. Im not sure why we are getting that error.

Comment: @RaviRock, because you didn't have any relation. In original query you were getting error because you had a query returning more than 1 rows where it should return 0 or 1 rows.

Comment: Am i missing something here?